# Why my user_id is updated to null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 model one for user(amitians) other is about.rb to store their details
they have a has_one relationship between them but problem is whenever I create a new about my about table has an amitan_id = null

When I tried to do the same in rails console. It works fine.

here is my code for models

About_amitians.rb

```
class AboutAmitian < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :amitian
end
```

Amitian.rb

```
has_one :about_amitian , foreign_key: "amitian_id"
```

My AboutAmitian controller

```
def new
  @about_amitian = current_amitian.build_about_amitian
end

def create
  @about_amitian = current_amitian.create_about_amitian!(about_amitian_params)
  if @about_amitian.save
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:notice] = 'success'
  else
    render root_url
  end    
end

private

def about_amitian_params
  params.require(:about_amitian).permit(:dob,:interest,:bio,:catch_phrase,:relationship_status)
end
```

In my server logs I have this query

```
Update 'about_amitians' set 'amitian_id' = NULL where 'about_amitian'.'id'  = 1
```

andhere are the params send via form

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6MtQlOfl4kU1BPMDT81m8rwwxSYdaQKpUEZbvnFw9ux1nVELSTSmaRNOgUCKNyTe2VrrkY01Ewn70hGWn/9wQg==", "about_amitian"=>{"dob"=>"m", "interest"=>"vm", "bio"=>"blyhjb", "catch_phrase"=>"hjkl", "relationship_status"=>"bljhbl"}, "commit"=>"Create About amitian"}
```

Comment: `current_amitian` is set?!?

Comment: ya.. using devise

Comment: may I know params when you add about?

Comment: I don't understand ... u mean attributes in my about table ?

Comment: When you submit form that time form will send parameters that I want to know.

Comment: ohh ya sure .. I will edit the q for you see

Comment: try this `current_amitian.about_amitian.create(about_amitian_params)`

Comment: no this won't work with has_one association

Comment: can u show schema for amitian and about_amitian?

Comment: if u want to see whether i have amitian_id in my about schema then yes I do.. their is nothing wrong in schema as my sql logs show an update to NULL on my amitian_id attribute. their is something wrong in controller or model

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it but this is insane... 
Everything is fine in the code.. problem is completely diff than what I assumed.
Whenever I submit the form everything is fyn and i have my amitian_id set correctly. But whenever I redirect to my new page... my amitian_id updates to NULL.
As you can see from code.. I redirect_to :back (i.e back to new) so my amitian_id updates to null.

Comment: I can't see how that would happen. You get an update just for rendering the `new` template? From the code you presented I think that the `foreign_key` option should be set in the `AboutAmitian` class instead of the `Amitian`, but if you say that's not the problem I don't have any more guesses.

Comment: i tried in so many ways.. everytime I redirect to new again.. I get an update of null... if i redirect to root_path after submission .. I have my amitian_id as 1 in my table which is correct.. but if i goto my about/new again .. it will be updated to null/... this is a big problem for me now ? :/

Comment: I would consider that a big problem as this is definitely _not_ the usual behavior. Perhaps there's something different about your `new` template triggering this.

Comment: I know , I asked a new q regarding this.. I am reading few documentations but nothing's working :/